# How to properly use nth-child css selector

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement some css with nth child selector and unfortunately it's not working.

```css
div.abc input:nth-child(3)
{
background: red;
color: red;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
  <div class="bc">
  <input type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="bc">
  <input type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="bc">
  <input type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="bc">
  <input type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the third input:

```
.abc div:nth-child(4) input
/* OR */
.abc div:nth-of-type(3) input
```

`nth-child` will seek all direct descendant tags so that would be:

```
<p> -> <div> -> <div> -> <div>
```

`nth-of-type` will seek all direct descendants of a specific type:

```
<div> -> <div> -> <div>
```

```css
.abc div:nth-child(4) input {
  color: gold;
}

.abc div:nth-of-type(3) input {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
  <div class="bc">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="bc">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="bc">
    <input type="text" value='TEST'/>
  </div>
  <div class="bc">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` tags are not siblings. They are wrapped in `div`s, so you need to select the `nth-child` of a `div` element and get the `input` inside that `div`.

```css
.abc > div:nth-child(4) > input{
  background: red;
  color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
  <div class="bc">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="bc">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="bc">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="bc">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing is not valid. `nth-of-child` is a selector for direct children of the parent container - in this case `abc` - and this parent element does not have any direct `input`-elements as children.

Instead, you need to target the `bc`-elements, as they are direct children of the the parent element `abc`, and then target the `input`.

In this example, I used `nth-of-type`. They are similiar, but `nth-of-type` targets DOM-elements directly, which are `div`s in this example.

```css
div.abc .bc:nth-of-type(3) input {
  background: red;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
  <div class="bc">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="bc">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="bc">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="bc">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```